# Stored procedure in DynamoDB

Tags: stored-procedures, apache-kafka, amazon-dynamodb

Can I get any examples on creating the stored procedures in DynamoDB.   I would like to read the data from Kafka topic and write to DynamoDB.  If anyone has done any example on stored procedure in DynamoDB with or without Kafka, let me know.

Lokesh Narayan

Comment: Does DynamoDB even *support* stored procedures?  This is news to me, if it does.  A citation from the docs would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure (i.e. similar to oracle PL/SQL) is not available in AWS DynamoDB at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedure are not available.

You can probably achieve a good performance by using AWS Lambda to do more complex db operations; in particular this approach could save you round-trips required if you are doing dependent operations on multiple tables; and it should be very fast since it would be performed inside of AWS.

p.s. this is somewhat similar approach that MongoDB has taken by storing [js functions stored on the db server](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/) (although in case of AWS it is better to keep this separated).

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own code in AWS Lambda to achieve that.